# How can i enter varchar values in case if the field type is integer in RedShift?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run this query:

```
select count(uid),
case when duration=0 then '0'
     when duration between 0 and 10 then '1-10 sec' end as Duration
from mr_session_log
where event_id=10     
group by
case when duration=0 then '0'
     when duration between 0 and 10 then '1-10 sec' end
```

But since the `duration` is integer Redshift doesn't allow me to enter "1-10 sec" value after the `then`.

Is there a way to to put different value from the original column value?

Comment: You forgot to provide the essential table definition.

Comment: "doesn't allow me to..." is not a good problem description. What error message do you get? Try to include all the information you've got in questions like this - what the data looks like, the desired output, the *exact* output you actually get, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is a *strongly-typed* language. [@John explains the basic problem in the query nicely.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32501992/939860) But I think we need more precision how to handle data types here. I suggest:

```sql
SELECT count(uid) AS ct
     , CASE WHEN duration = 0 THEN text '0 sec' -- explicit type for string literal
            WHEN duration BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN '1-10 sec' -- coerced to same type
       END AS duration
FROM   mr_session_log
WHERE  event_id = 10     
GROUP  BY 2;
```

You can use `'0 sec'::text` or `cast('0 sec' AS text)` as well.

In modern Postgres `'0 sec'` or even `'0'` without explicit type does the same because a *string literal* defaults to type `text` in most contexts.

You *could* even use `0::text` or `cast(0 AS text)`, but it's pointless to provide a string as *numeric literal* and make Postgres cast *twice* (first the numeric literal is automatically cast to `int` in this case, then `int` to `text`).

Read the [chapter about constants in the Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS). (I wouldn't know of proper documentation for Redshift.)

`GROUP  BY 2` is just syntax shorthand referring to the 2nd `SELECT` item. If that should not be implemented in Redshift, repeat the `CASE` expression like you did before.

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you are mixing types within a column.

- `when duration=0 then 0` returns an **integer**
- `when duration between 0 and 10 then '1-10 sec'` returns a **string**
- They are both populating the same `Duration` output column (which is not the same as the original `duration` column)

I recommend you change the first result into a `string`, eg: `when duration=0 then '0 sec'`

Comment: Or just `'0'`. Or `0::text` which is shorthand for `CAST(0 as text)`.

Comment: hi, thanks but look now on the query it steel doesn't work

Comment: Could you update your question to show the new query and error message?

Comment: @IMSoP: Nitpicking: `0::text` works, but  ... I added another answer.